# MySQL "pileup" when importing rows

Tags: mysql, cron, database-performance

I have the following cron process running every hour to update global game stats:

- Create temporary table
- For each statistic, insert rows into the temporary table (stat key, user, score, rank)
- Truncate main stats table
- Copy data from temporary table to main table

The last step causes massive backlog in queries. Looking at `SHOW PROCESSLIST` I see a bunch of `updating`-status queries that are stuck until the copy completes (which may take up to a minute).

However I did notice that it's not like it has consecutive query IDs piling up, many queries get completed just fine. So it almost seems like it's a "thread" that gets stuck or something. Also of note is that the stuck updates have nothing in common with the ongoing copy (different tables, etc)

So:

- Can I have cron connect to MySQL on a dedicated "thread" such that its disk activity (or whatever it is) doesn't lock other updates, OR
- Am I misinterpreting what's going on, and if so how can I find out what the actual case is?

Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: What do the stuck processes say they're waiting on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL threads are not perfectly named. If you're a Java dev, for example, you might make some untrue assumptions about MySQL threads based on your Java knowledge.

For some reason that's hard to diagnose from a distance, your copy step is blocking some queries from completing.  If you're curious about which ones try doing

```
 SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

and try to make sense of the result.

In the meantime, you might consider a slightly different approach to refreshing these hourly stats.

1. create a new, non temporary table, calling it something like `stats_11` for the 11am update. If the table with that name already existed, drop the old one first.
2. populate that table as needed.
3. add the indexes it needs. Sometimes populating the table is faster if the indexes aren't in place while you're doing it.
4. `create or replace view stats as select * from stats_11`

Next hour, do the same with `stats_12`. The idea is to have your `stats` view pointing to a valid stats table almost always.

This should reduce your exposure time to the stats-table building operaiton.

Comment: That's interesting. So build a table for the given hour, and update a view into it... How would this work with foreign keys referencing user IDs and the like?

Comment: Before: 1 minute. After: <5ms. Yup, I think that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to completely rebuild the table, this is the best:

```
CREATE TABLE new_stats LIKE stats;
... fill up new_stats by whatever means ...
RENAME TABLE stats TO old_stats, new_stats TO stats;
DROP TABLE old_stats;
```

There is zero interference because table `real` is always available and always has a complete set of rows.  (OK, `RENAME` does take a minuscule amount of time.)

No VIEWs, no TEMPORARY table, no copying the data over, no need for 24 tables.

You could consider doing the task "continually", rather than hourly.  This becomes especially beneficial if the table gets so big that the hourly cron job takes more than one hour!